# How to setup a template with multiple items for a list in ui5

Tags: list, templates, sapui5

in my UI5 App, there is a list, in which I want to show more than one DisplayListItem. Therefore I set up a template for the list to bind with 
`oList.bindAggregation("items", "/my_path", oListTemplate);` 
If i build the template like this: 
`oListTemplate = new sap.m.DisplayListItem(...);` 
Anything works perfekt. 
But now I need to give several `new sap.m.DisplayListItem(...)` with an array like `oListTempate = [new sap.m.DisplayListItem(...), new sap.m.DisplayListItem(...),..];` into one template. If I do so, I get an error for not having a template given:
`Error: Missing template or factory function for aggregation items`

Is it not possible to give more than one item with the template. At the sap docu: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.34.9/docs/guide/91f057786f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html there is the line:

> A template is not necessarily a single control as shown in the example above, but can also be a tree of controls.

Because of this, I think it is possible, but I don't know how to do it.

 
thank you in advance

Comment: try to loop over your array adding each item with oList.addItem() : https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.60.8/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/methods/addItem

Comment: but i dont think display list items are what you are looking for please describe what your usecase is. I ll may be able to offer a better solution

Comment: I tried addItem() but instead of showing all items I simply showed the last one. I need to display four different informations, each with label and value, in that list. also need to apply a filter, which i do after a button press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through your results and add a DisplayListItem for every result:

```
var aItems = [];
oResponse.results.forEach(function(oResult){
  aItems.push(new sap.m.DisplayListItem({
                    label: "oResult.name"
                })
  );
});
```

Add your Array to your List:

```
var oList = new sap.m.List({
    headerText: "Test list",
    items: aItems
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to specify the template is this:

```
oList.bindAggregation("items", {
path: "/my_path",
template: oListTemplate
});
```

Adding items to List by creating individual items may result in performance issues.